# no se actualiza el avatar subiendo la imagen a imgur mediante su api

Tags: php, html, pdo

Hola tengo un problema al enviar el formulario este no sube la imagen a imgur ni actualiza la base de datos, uso este sistema de carga a imgur en otro codigo y funciona perfectamente pero no se por que aqui no me actualiza segun lo que creo es que el formulario es el problema y no la carga a imgur 
el codigo lo saque de aqui `https://subinsb.com/uploading-images-using-imgur-api-in-php/`

```
<?php
$user_id = $_GET['user'];
$connection  = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=;charset=utf8mb4',"","");
$connection ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
      $image = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
      $client_id=" [api imgur]  ";
      $handle = fopen($image, "r");
      $data = fread($handle, filesize($image));
      $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
      $timeout = 30;
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
      $out = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close ($curl);
      $pms = json_decode($out,true);
      $url=$pms['data']['link'];
      //insert into database with a prepared statement
      $stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user SET avatar = '$url' WHERE user_id =  $user_id");
      $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
      var_dump($stmt);
    }
}
?>
<?php
$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = "'.$user_id.'" ');
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(isset($result)) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $result['avatar']?>">
    <form  method="post" >
        <input style="display: block;" type="file" name="img" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlFile1" placeholder="Pega urls(.png,jpg,gif)" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
        <button style="border-radius: 19px 19px 19px 19px;" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary postMention" id="postear">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
    <?php
}else{?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: no sé si soy muy novato en php, pero amí me parece que en `$stmt->execute(array($user_id));` deberías de agregar un parámetro para la URL

Comment: Has tratado de debugear el codigo, colocando salidas de cada paso que se ejecuta?? Si la imagen esta llegando, si se conecta correctamente a la api, si hace el update?

Comment: el código para subir a imgur funciona en su totalidad lo uso en otra parte de mi web y va perfectamente

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te sale mejor si ejecutas un `query` en vez de un `prepare`, pues no lo estas utilizando como debe ser así que da lo mismo que uses uno o el otro.

```
$stmt = $connection->query("UPDATE user SET avatar = '$url' WHERE user_id =  $user_id");
$stmt->execute();
```

de esta forma obtienes el mismo resultado, de la forma que tienes no es la forma correcta de usar el prepare, si deseas entender un poco mas el tema del prepare aquí te comparto. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

PD: agrégale esto:

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

al form como atributo. parece ser que la imagen no esta llegando, colócalo y me cuentas.

Answer (score 4):

No estás utilizando correctamente la función [PDO::prepare()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

Para tu caso deberías usar algo del estilo:

```php
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user SET avatar = :url WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(':url' => $url, ':user_id' => $user_id));
```

Como se muestra en el ejemplo de la documentación de PHP, también puedes utilizar algo como (manteniendo el orden de los parámetros):

```php
$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user SET avatar = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($url, $user_id));
```

Comment: la segunda forma que muestras no es válida para PDO y solo funciona con mysqli

Comment: No estoy exento de cometer equivocaciones, pero como se puede ver en la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php#example-1068), la segunda forma parece una manera válida.